# Update Angular 8 Cannot read property ngInjectableDef of undefined

Tags: angular, angular8

I've updated my angular project from v7 to v8.2.14 and now when I run `ng serve` it gives me this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined
  at getInjectableDef (core.js:361)
  at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30377)
  at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31578)
  at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:734)
  at ɵɵinject (core.js:744)
  at injectArgs (core.js:834)
  at core.js:16346
  at _callFactory (core.js:30486)
  at _createProviderInstance (core.js:30429)
  at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30388)
```

I've searched a lot but none of the solutions solved my problem.

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
  "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.14",
  "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
  "@angular/cli": "^8.3.23",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
  ...
}
```

Update:

It works when I run `ng build`. I only get the error when I run `ng serve`.

Comment: might be a duplicate question. Please check these https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271317/3209523 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190823/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-nginjectabledef-of-undefined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186927/angular-8-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-invalid-of-undefined and if it is duplicate, please mark it.

Comment: @canbax Thanks but I've already checked them and although my project is really big, I checked all the classes and I didn't see any problem

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in here just in case this helps anyone. I had a similar problem to this and none of the links in the replies to the parent comment were able to resolve my problem, so I'm posting my experience just in case it's helpful to anyone in the future.

I was working with an Angular typescript project that was running A.O.K when doing development testing but was bombing when deployed when accessing a specific component.   The error I received was a very vague, 'Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of null'

After poking around for a bit, I discovered the problem was related to an 'export default class' statement in a class.  I updated it to export class and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Still can't figure out the root cause for the issue.

But I just:

1. Removed the `node_modules` by running: `npx rimraf node_modules`(make sure you're on `npm` >= `v5.2.0` or just install **[`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf)** globally)
2. Installed them again: `npm i`

And voila! My project's running again.

> **PS:** Can't guarantee if it will work for you as well. But worth a try coz it worked for me.